# How to restrict access to activeadmin dashboard when using single user model for app and CMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, activeadmin

I'm using single `User` model for `adtiveadmin` and application itself. I've found a [solution](https://gist.github.com/1264060) to restrict access to activeadmin's model pages using `CanCan` and `rolify`. Note that in the example above they are using constants to create roles and i use `rolify` gem. Nevertheless I can easily access activeadmin's dashboard. When i try to access models in the CMS i'm redirected to application's root page with displaying an error message saying i am not authorized to access this page.

Is there a way to restrict access to activeadmin's dashboard and models so that i'm redirected
to activeadmin's authorization page?

Here is my active_admin_resource initializer

```
#config/initializers/active_admin_resources.rb
ActiveAdmin::ResourceController.class_eval do
protected
  def current_ability
    @current_ability ||= AdminAbility.new(current_user)
  end
end
```

Ability class in defined as follows:

```
#app/models/admin_ability.rb
class AdminAbility < ActiveRecord::Base
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new
  if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all
  end
end
```

end

Activeadmin's model is defined this way:

```
#app/admin/some_model.rb
ActiveAdmin.register SomeModel do
  controller.authorize_resource
end
```

And finally activeadmin's routes are defined as follows:

```
#config/routes.rb
Rallypoint::Application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> .. i'm redirected to application's root page ..

Most apps have a `rescue_from(CanCan::AccessDenied)` in their `ApplicationController` as described in the wiki page [Exception Handling](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Exception-Handling).

> [I want to be] redirected to activeadmin's authorization page

Try overriding that `rescue_from` within activeadmin.